# Need of an object in synchronised block

Tags: java, multithreading

As per my understanding, if we add synchronized keyword in our code, whole block of code inside it will be locked for the other threads. In that case, why do we need to specify a particular object in synchronized keyword. 
for eg. **synchronized(lockObject)**. what is the use of lockObject here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if we add synchronized keyword in our code, whole block of code inside it will be locked for the other threads.

Incorrect. `synchronized` involves a mechanism entirely separate from your block of code: acquiring and releasing a *mutual exclusion lock*. Java has the concept of `synchronized` blocks as a convenience to ensure proper release of a lock after it's acquired.

So, what actually happens is that your thread acquires the monitor associated with the instance given in the parentheses, then proceeds to execute the block of code, then releases the monitor. Meanwhile no other thread can acquire *that particular monitor*, but it can very well acquire any other object's monitor. If you don't take care to always have the same object involved in the synchronized block, you will get no mutual exclusion.

Comment: Well, it does have something rather important to do with the block of code:  It guarantees that the code will not be executed by a thread that doesn't hold the lock, and it guarantees that the thread won't leave the block without releasing the lock.  Maybe what you're trying to say is that the code is not what needs protection: The reason for using a synchronized block is to protect the _data_ upon which the block operates.

Comment: My point is that mutual exclusion happens through a mechanism which is entirely separate from the block of code covered by the `synchronized` block. The intention is to clear this up for OP, who seems to be stuck in a paradigm where the block of code itself is somehow "locked out".

Comment: OK, I get it.  Yes, that's another common noob question, "How come two threads were able to execute this same synchronized block at the same time?"  And, the answer always is, "because they were not synchronized on the same object."

Comment: Java's design is misleading to beginners because it tries to hide too much of what's really going on. It makes them make the wrong mental connections and form a false picture which they then use to produce incorrect code.

Comment: so the object which we give in parenthesis will not be locked for use right? For example. i give 
synchronized(sharedQueue){
int a=10;
}
, so will that the sharedQueue be blocked for using the other threads?

Comment: Only the other blocks of code acquiring the same lock will be locked out. You must manually specify this for every such block.

Comment: Yes.. I got that point. I have somewhere in my code, sharedQueue is used. Will that be blocked for use if i synchronize with sharedQueue?

Comment: Thanks... I got the answer... It is not locking the object, it is getting the monitor of the object. And no two threads can access the code which is synchronized with this object.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have 2 resources you want to synchronize; the bathroom and the fridge.

You want people to be able to grab a snack from the fridge even if someone is using the bathroom, don't you?

So you use different locks on the fridge and on the bathroom.

In programming terms, that means that each independent resource can have it's own lockObject.

Note that a resource can have several methods that access them - **all the accessors of the same resource should use the same lock**! After all, if you have two doors into the bathroom it wouldn't do much good if you only locked one of them.

Comment: +1 for the two doors analogy.  IMO one of the biggest misconceptions that noobs have about `synchronized` is in thinking that methods need synchronization.  It's not the methods that are important, it's the _data_.